# Flip x and y axis using basic plot function

Tags: r, plot, axis

I have a a vector v3 with levels: setosa versicolor virginica

When I plot the vector using the basic plot function;

```
plot(v3, type = "s", xlim = NULL, ylim = c(0,50), 
main = "Plot 2", ylab = 'Frequency', col = "blue")
```

I get the following plot

[image: initial_plot]

But the output I would like to create looks like this:

[image: final_plot]

I know certain (more elegant) solutions exist but I would like to create this without installing & loading additional packages. I tried the following with axis:

```
axis(1, at = c(0,50), labels = FALSE, tick = TRUE)
axis(2, at = levels(v3), labels = FALSE, tick = TRUE)
```

But R would not accept it.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Try looking at `?barplot` which has a `horiz=` parameter to make things horizontal.

Comment: @MrFlick  thanks for the suggestions. Seems like a good solution but doesn't work for me since R returns "height must be vector or matrix". v3 is class = "factor", does that limit how I can work with that?

Comment: Then you can pass that to `table()` as is done in the answer from @ChrisRuehlemann

Comment: appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems what you are looking for is a barplot  rather than a scatter plot. Let's say you have data like this:

**DATA**:

```
set.seed(321)
v3 <- sample(c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"), 100, replace = T)
v3
  [1] "versicolor" "versicolor" "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"     "versicolor" "versicolor" "setosa"    
  [9] "virginica"  "virginica"  "setosa"     "virginica"  "versicolor" "virginica"  "versicolor" "virginica" 
 [17] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "virginica"  "versicolor" "versicolor" "virginica"  "versicolor"
 [25] "virginica"  "versicolor" "setosa"     "versicolor" "setosa"     "virginica"  "setosa"     "setosa"    
 [33] "virginica"  "versicolor" "setosa"     "virginica"  "versicolor" "setosa"     "versicolor" "setosa"    
 [41] "virginica"  "versicolor" "setosa"     "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor" "versicolor" "setosa"    
 [49] "setosa"     "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica"  "setosa"     "virginica"  "versicolor" "versicolor"
 [57] "setosa"     "setosa"     "virginica"  "setosa"     "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "virginica" 
 [65] "virginica"  "setosa"     "virginica"  "versicolor" "versicolor" "versicolor" "virginica"  "versicolor"
 [73] "virginica"  "setosa"     "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "versicolor" "versicolor" "versicolor"
 [81] "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"     "virginica"  "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"    
 [89] "versicolor" "versicolor" "virginica"  "setosa"     "virginica"  "virginica"  "virginica"  "versicolor"
 [97] "setosa"     "virginica"  "virginica"  "setosa"
```

What you cannot do is plot factor levels; you can only count the number of times the levels occur in your data: these frequencies you can plot. You can do this by tabulating the vector `v3` using the `table` function. To flip the bars into **horizontal** position you can use the argument `horiz = TRUE` (doing that will also necessitate that you put the label `Frequency` onto the x-axis rather than the y-axis):

```
barplot(table(v3), horiz = T, main = "Plot 2", 
        xlab = 'Frequency', 
        ylab = 'Species',
        col = 'blue')
```

**RESULT**:

The resulting barplot would look like this:
[image]